# Scrapy missing one record

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

Newbie to scrapy, been trying to crawl website data from https://www.citypopulation.de/en/southkorea/busan/admin/, but it is missing a record from the table.

Able to crawl the rest of the records with no issue, example:

```
<tbody class="admin1">
<tr class="rname" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AdministrativeArea" onclick="javascript:sym('21080')"><td class="rname" id="i21080" data-wiki="Buk District, Busan" data-wd="Q50394" data-area="39.726" data-density="7052.7362"><a href="javascript:sym('21080')"><span itemprop="name">Buk-gu</span></a> [<span itemprop="name">North Distrikt</span>]</td><td class="rstatus">City District</td><td class="rnative"><span itemprop="name">북구</span></td><td class="rpop prio4">329,336</td><td class="rpop prio3">302,141</td><td class="rpop prio2">299,182</td><td class="rpop prio1">280,177</td><td class="sc"><a itemprop="url" href="/en/southkorea/busan/admin/21080__buk_gu/">→</a></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Missing row when there is no link under the `<td class="sc">`, example:

```
<tbody class="admin0">
<tr><td class="rname">Busan</td><td class="rstatus">Metropolitan City</td><td class="rnative"><span itemprop="name">부산광역시</span></td><td class="rpop prio4">3,523,582</td><td class="rpop prio3">3,414,950</td><td class="rpop prio2">3,448,737</td><td class="rpop prio1">3,349,016</td><td class="sc"></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Code:

```
from gc import callbacks
import scrapy

class WebsiteItem(scrapy.Item):
    item_name = scrapy.Field()
    item_status = scrapy.Field()

class WebsiteSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = "posts"
    start_urls = ["https://www.citypopulation.de/en/southkorea/"]

    rules = (
        scrapy.spiders.Rule(scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor(restrict_css="div#prov_div > ul > li > a"), follow=True),
        scrapy.spiders.Rule(scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor(restrict_css="table#tl > tbody > tr > td"), callback="parse")
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        website_item = WebsiteItem()

        website_item['item_name'] = response.css("td.rname span::text").get()
        website_item['item_status'] = response.css("td.rstatus::text").get()

        return website_item
```

I assume it is because of the rule that is enforcing to crawl based on link, but have no idea how to solve this while still loop through each records in the table.

```
rules = (
        scrapy.spiders.Rule(scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor(restrict_css="div#prov_div > ul > li > a"), follow=True),
        scrapy.spiders.Rule(scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor(restrict_css="table#tl > tbody > tr > td"), callback="parse")
    )
```

Appreciate if anyone can help to point out what am I missing here.

Comment: sorry how is it an empty <td>? i'm able to get the text 'City District' under <td class="rstatus"> for first example but unable to get the text 'Metropolitan City' under <td class="rstatus"> for the second example

Comment: @Coastie your code works fine for me

Comment: @SuperUser did it return the 'Busan' row for you?

Comment: You're righrt @Coastie, I was looking at the last `td` tag.

Comment: @Coastie sorry I didn't understand at first. You'll need to find another way because this tag doesn't have a URL so the rule doesn't send it to the callback because the link extractor doesn't have any url to process

Comment: I added a simple example of how you can get the name/status pairs, including Busan. You will probably want to include the example in scraper logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get those name/status pairs:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd

class SkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sk'
    allowed_domains = ['citypopulation.de']
    start_urls = ["https://www.citypopulation.de/en/southkorea/busan/admin/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        df = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            yield {
                'name': row['Name'],
                'status': row['Status']
            }
```

Run with `scrapy crawl sk -o sk_areas.json`, and it will produce a json file with this structure:

```
[
{"name": "Buk-gu [North Distrikt]", "status": "City District"},
{"name": "Deokcheon 1-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Deokcheon 2-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Deokcheon 3-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Geumgok-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Gupo 1-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Gupo 2-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Gupo 3-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
[...]
{"name": "Yeonsan 6-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Yeonsan 8-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Yeonsan 9-dong", "status": "Quarter"},
{"name": "Busan", "status": "Metropolitan City"}
]
```

As you can see, it will include Busan as well.

Comment: wow it works this way too, alright i just have to loop through the pages now, thanks a lot!